# Windows XP: how to disable automatic encryption on downloaded files

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, encryption

I have Windows XP SP3 and every file I download is automatically encrypted no matter what directory I save the downloaded file in. So it's not as simple as turning off encryption of any specific directory, the file will be downloaded as encrypted regardless of whether the directory is encrypted or not.

Is there a policy or registry setting somewhere to disable this automatic encryption?

(EDIT: I doubt it's malware since this OS was just installed on this machine. It's my work PC and by default I think there's some group policy or other setting which not only sets everything in My Documents to encrypted, but also everything I download, no matter where it's downloaded to. )

Comment: How is the file encrypted?  What are you seeing that makes you think the file is encrypted?

Comment: The file's text is green and under its properties -> advanced the checkbox for enabled encryption is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a possible malware infection. Only folders marked for encryption should have this behavior. If you know you are Not infected, you could use Microsoft System Restore and pick a date before this behavior started.

Comment: I doubt it's malware since this OS was just installed on this machine. It's my work PC and by default I think there's some group policy or other setting which not only sets everything in My Documents to encrypted, but also everything I download, no matter where it's downloaded to.

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit of info, you might include it in your original post, would it not be easy to ask your IT department about this issue?

Comment: Welcome, hope this additional info can help generate a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a stand alone computer you have to add a registry entry, but I'm not 100% sure about what will happen to the existing encrypted files as this may render them inaccessible.

1. In the Run dialog box, type regedit.exe.
2. Navigate to the subkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE \Microsoft
   \Windows NT\CurrentVersion\EFS.
3. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
4. Enter EfsConfiguration for the value name and 1 for the value data to
   disable EFS (a value of 0 enables EFS).
5. Restart the computer.

Export your registry first as a safe guard or add a restore point at a minimum

Comment: Surprisingly, the /EFS key does not exist there or under HKEY_CURRENT_USER either.